# Unwanted margin around header

Tags: jquery, html, css

For some reason I keep getting a margin around my header which I don't want to be there, I have tried loads of things to get rid of it but nothing is working.

[image: Example:]

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/testing/main.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cookie' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anonymous+Pro:400,400italic,700italic,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="header-fixed">
      <div class="header-limiter">
        <h1><a href="http://itzjavacraft.tk">ItzJavaCraft<span></span></a></h1>
        <nav>
          <a href="#" class="selected">Home</a>
          <a href="#">Blog</a>
          <a href="#">Tutorials</a>
          <a href="#">News</a>
          <a href="#">Contact</a>
          <a href="#">About</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="header-fixed-placeholder">
    </div>
    <div class="wrap">
      <article class="main">

      </article>
    </div>
    <footer>
      <hr>
      <div id="footer-links">
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true"></i> Facebook</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://twitter.com/itzjavacraft" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i> Twitter</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://instagram.com/itzjavacraft" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i> Instagram</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://vine.co/u/1269681750234615808" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-vine" aria-hidden="true"></i> Vine</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="https://youtube.com/channel/UCZhk1PN4RzBXe63bqg0GtHw" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play" aria-hidden="true"></i> YouTube</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://twitch.tv/itzjavacraft" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitch" aria-hidden="true"></i> Twitch</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://soundcloud.com/itzjavacraft" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-soundcloud" aria-hidden="true"></i> SoundCloud</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.reddit.com/user/ItzJavaCraft" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-reddit-alien" aria-hidden="true"></i> Reddit</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div> 
          <ul>
            <li><a href="http://github.com/itzjavacraft" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-github" aria-hidden="true"></i> GitHub</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/users/6125445/itzjavacraft" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-stack-overflow" aria-hidden="true"></i> Stack Overflow</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://jsfiddle.net/user/ItzJavaCraft" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-jsfiddle" aria-hidden="true"></i> JSFiddle</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <p class="footer">Oh, hello there. My name is Java. No, not the programming language! Well, this is awkward. Not much else to be said... uhm... enjoy your stay, I guess!</p>
      <a href="http://itzjavacraft.tk">
        <img src="/assets/images/logo.png" alt="ItzJavaCraft" style="width:149px;height:16px;"/>
      </a>
    </footer>
    <div class="menu">
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        var showHeaderAt = 150;
        var win = $(window),
            body = $('body');
        if(win.width() > 600){
          win.on('scroll', function(e){
            if(win.scrollTop() > showHeaderAt) {
              body.addClass('fixed');
            }
            else {
              body.removeClass('fixed');
            }
          });
        }
      });
    </script>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Toolkit */

hr {
  border: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  }

img.center-align {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  }

.noselect {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */ 
  -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome/Safari/Opera */ 
  -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror */ 
  -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */ 
  -ms-user-select: none; /* IE/Edge */ 
  user-select: none; /* non-prefixed version, currently not supported by any browser */ 
  }

/* Links */

a:link {
  color: black;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 75%;
  }

a:visited {
  color: black;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 75%;
  }

a:hover {
  color: #9700bd;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-size: 75%;
  }

a:active {
  color: #9700bd;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 75%;
  }

/* Header */

.header-fixed {
  background-color:#292c2f;
  box-shadow:0 1px 1px #ccc;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  height: 80px;
  color: #ffffff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top:-100px;

  -webkit-transition:top 0.3s;
  transition:top 0.3s;
  }

.header-fixed .header-limiter {
  max-width: 1200px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  }

.header-fixed-placeholder{
  height: 80px;
  display: none;
  }

.header-fixed .header-limiter h1 {
  float: left;
  font: normal 28px Cookie, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin: 0;
  }

.header-fixed .header-limiter h1 span {
  color: #5383d3;
  }

.header-fixed .header-limiter a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  }

.header-fixed .header-limiter nav {
  font:16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: 40px;
  float: right;
  }

.header-fixed .header-limiter nav a{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 5px;
  text-decoration:none;
  color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 0.9;
  }

.header-fixed .header-limiter nav a:hover{
  opacity: 1;
  }

.header-fixed .header-limiter nav a.selected {
  color: #608bd2;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 1;
  }

body.fixed .header-fixed {
  padding: 10px 40px;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  }

body.fixed .header-fixed-placeholder {
  display: block;
  }

body.fixed .header-fixed .header-limiter h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 30px;
  }

body.fixed .header-fixed .header-limiter nav {
  line-height: 28px;
  font-size: 13px;
  }

@media all and (max-width: 600px) {

      .header-fixed {
        padding: 20px 0;
        height: 75px;
        }

      .header-fixed .header-limiter h1 {
        float: none;
        margin: -8px 0 10px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 24px;
        line-height: 1;
        }

      .header-fixed .header-limiter nav {
        line-height: 1;
        float:none;
        }

      .header-fixed .header-limiter nav a {
        font-size: 13px;
        }

      body.fixed .header-fixed {
        display: none;
        }

  }

/* Footer */

footer {
  text-align: center;
  } 

#footer-links {
  display: flex;
  } 

#footer-links div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  }

#footer-links ul { 
  list-style: none;
  }

p.footer {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  clear: both;
  font-size: 75%;
  font-family: 'Anonymous Pro';
  }

/* Other */

body {

  }

article.main {
height: 1500px;
}

div.wrap {
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  }
```

A live version of the site can be found [here](http://itzjavacraft.tk/testing).

Please help! It would be very appreciated.

Comment: it's from the body tag

Comment: This has got to be one of the most asked questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add following CSS to your CSS.

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
body{
    margin:0;
    }
```

should solve your problem.Fiddle here- [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/11j2gqry/2/)

Comment: This was one of the things I tried, it didn't work for me.

Comment: Then the problem must be related to the browser...It works.Fiddle coming soon

Answer (score 0):

use this css code , this code remove all browser default margin and padding value

```
*{
margin: 0;
padding : 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
*{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 }
```

However it would be better to use reset.css or normalize.css. This would remove all the other CSS default properties and you won't run into any such trouble.

Use these cdn links to add anyone of the files

[Normalize.css](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/normalize)

[Reset.css](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/meyer-reset)